# Efficient way to build a MySQL update query in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pylons

I have a class variable called attributes which lists the instance variables I want to update in a database:

```
attributes = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'name', 'name_url',
              'email', 'password', 'password_salt', 'picture_id']
```

Each of the class attributes are updated upon instantiation.

I would like to loop through each of the attributes and build a MySQL update query in the form of:

```
UPDATE members SET id = self._id, first_name = self._first name ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Ic(object):
  attributes = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'name', 'name_url',
              'email', 'password', 'password_salt', 'picture_id']

  def __init__(self): ...

  # and other methods that set all the attributes on self

  def updater(self):
    sqlbase = 'UPDATE members SET %s WHERE whateveryouwanthere'
    setpieces = []
    values = []
    for atr in self.attributes:
      setpieces.append('%s = ?' % atr)
      values.append(getattr(self, atr, None))
    return sqlbase % ', '.join(setpieces), values
```

The caller needs to build up an object of class `Ic` appropriately, then do

```
sql, values = theobj.updater()
```

and lastly call `mycursor.execute(sql, values)` on whatever DB API cursor it has to the database which needs to be updated (I have no idea about the WHERE conditions you want to use to identify the sepcific record to update, which is why I put a `whatreveryouwanthere` placeholder there;-).

Comment: Hi Alex -- Thank you.  How can I modify this code to also include "WHERE id = 123" ... Ideally the sqlbase should read: sqlbase = 'UPDATE members SET %s WHERE id = %s' but I am not sure how to handle that second %s for replacement with the id.  Thank you!

Comment: @ensnare, if your `whateveryouwanthere` has a `id = ?`, append the value you want for the `id` to `values` (after the `for` loop and just before you `return`). Makes no sense to use `%s` where normal value substitution works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

First question: will all the variables in attributes be used? If so the easiest way is probably to use the DBAPI's execute method.

assuming your cursor is instantiated as csr:

```
sql="UPDATE mytable SET phone=? where username=?"
variables = ("a phone number","a username")
csr.execute(sql,variables)
```

There are additional ways of doing it, such as using dictionaries, positional indicators, etc.. see [DBAPI FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq) for more details.